# How can I encode my data for machine learning methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I would like to encode my input letters of strings for machine learning methods. Let's assume that my train data looks in this way:

```
  score     text
    1   show photos
    1   show my photos
    2   who are you?
```

At the moment I do something like this:

```
for index, row in train_set.iterrows():

    list2 = []

    list2 = list(row.text.lower())

    for n, key in enumerate(list2):

        if key in dictionary:

            list2[n] = dictionary[key]

        else:

            dictionary[key] = i
            list2[n] = i
            i += 1

    train_set.set_value(index,'text', list2)
```

And as a result for this example data I get:

```
  score                 text
    1    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 0]
    1    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 0]
    2    [3, 1, 2, 4, 10, 13, 9, 4, 8, 2, 19, 21]
```

As you know for instance for neural networks it is not a proper way to use this values, so it seems to me that the one hot encoding will be the best solution in this case. I wonder what will be the most efficient way to convert these values in `text` column of `test_set` dataframe and also column `text` in `train_set` dataframe which looks like `test_set` but obviously doesn't have first column with expected values. I think that in both cases I should have the same size of columns after using one hot encoding and the same index and row should correspond to the same character in both `test_set` and `train_set` dataframe. I hope that you understand what I mean. If not please just let me know. I will try to explain it in a more clear way. Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Well if you are after one hot encoding then this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618245/how-to-one-hot-encode-sentences-at-the-character-level

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to have a custom `Prepper` class to encode your training set. As the training set gets encoded, the `Prepper` class object records the (word , one-hot index) correspondance.

You would then use the same `Prepper` object to encode your test set.

A rough sketelon of `Prepper` class would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Prepper(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.vocab = defaultdict(lambda : len(self.vocab))

   def encode_train_word(self, train_word):
      return self.vocab[train_word]

   def encode_test_word(self, test_word):
      if test_word in self.vocab:
         return self.vocab[test_words]
      else:
         return -1 # index for unknown token
```

If I had to re-take your code snippet, it would look like:

```
prepper = Prepper()

for index, row in train_set.iterrows():
   list2 = list(row.text.lower())
   encoded_list_2 = [prepper.encode_train_word(word) for word in list2]

   train_set.set_value(index, 'text', encoded_list_2)

## and for the test set

for index, row in test_set.iterrows():
   list2 = list(row.text.lower())
   encoded_list_2 = [prepper.encode_test_word(word) for word in list2]

   test_set.set_value(index, 'text', encoded_list_2)
```