# One hot Encoding at character Level

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

So I was following some of the examples provided on this post: [How to one-hot-encode sentences at the character level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618245/how-to-one-hot-encode-sentences-at-the-character-level)

And they seem to hot encoding at character level. However, I am not able to figure out to hot encode at character level for a string with ints in it.

for example:

```
"hello" # h=7, e=4 l=11 o=14
```

would be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I was able to achieve that with the help of the post I mentioned above. But would someone be able to help me hot encoding the following:

```
"Hello0311"
```

Any help and guidance is highly apprecaited

Comment: In the function provided in the accepted answer, just replace `alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase` with `alphabet=string.digits+string.ascii_letters`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the singleton encoding function provided by Keras directly. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train_label = [7,4,11,11,14]
y_train_label_onehot = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train_label)
print('one_hot:',y_train_label_onehot)
```

The results：[image: Figure one hot]